# How to switch on property name of an object property?

Tags: c#, wpf

I really, really, really hate having magic strings. And switch statements are super convenient especially when paired with nameof(). However, I'm running into an issue with switching on an incoming property type.

In my wpf application I'm binding a grid column to the property of an object. So when the ShowingEditor event is triggered, the e.Column.FieldName that comes across is the same as the value in my binding. However, I can't work out how to switch off that name.

Below is some sample code which illustrates the issue.

```
public class Program
{
    public class A
    {
        public B AStringValue
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public int IntValue
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }

    public class B
    {
        public string StringValue
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        string input = "AStringValue.StringValue";
        switch (input)
        {
            case nameof(A.AStringValue.StringValue): // want to be "AStringValue.StringValue"
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

How can I switch on the name of the property of an object property via a direct reference to the type? While I can of course hard code the name of the property as it comes across in the event handler, I want to avoid this if at all possible. Using direct references to the property names means that if I rename it in one location I can rely on my IDE to rename it in other use cases without breaking my code.

Comment: `nameof(x) + "." + nameof(x.y)` is a constant expression. For what it's worth.

Comment: Ick. :( I appreciate it though!

Comment: What version of C# are you using. C# 7 is the first to not use the constant pattern for switch statements (which should allow what you are trying to do).

Comment: @Kevin 7, but the problem isn't the non-constant, it's that I get an exception that I need to provide an object reference because it thinks I'm referencing the value of StringValue, and not attempting to get the name of the property.

Comment: In general you can reference property via direct reference to type. For example, `nameof(A.AStringValue)` will work fine, even though outside of nameof it's not a valid syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static string GetName<TSource>(Expression<Func<TSource, object>> lambda)
{
    var code = lambda.Body.ToString();
    var match = Regex.Match(code, @"^\w+\.((?:\w+\.)*\w+)$");
    if (!match.Success)
        throw new ArgumentException("Unexpected expression tree");

    return match.Groups[1].Value;
}
```

And you use it like this:
`GetName<A>(q => q.AStringValue.StringValue)`.

This code gets the string representation of the actual expression tree. It can easily give undesired results in a lot of cases (method access, using a local var...), so the regex makes sure the output is what you expect.

And of course there's the performance cost. To avoid analyzing the lambda and running the regex on every call for every option, you should cache the results instead of using a switch.